# Jquery click event on list of anchor

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have created list of anchors.On clicking the link,I want to add CSS Class(using addClass) to the link I have clicked upon.

```
<ul id = "menu">
        <li id="mnuLectures" runat="server">
            <asp:HyperLink NavigateUrl = "~/Lectures.aspx" Text="Lectures" runat = "server" ID= "hypLectures" />
        </li>
        <li id="mnuBooks" runat="server">
            <asp:HyperLink NavigateUrl = "~/Books.aspx" Text="Books" runat = "server" ID= "hypBooks" />
        </li>
        <li id="mnuArticles" runat="server">
            <asp:HyperLink NavigateUrl = "~/Articles.aspx" Text="Articles" runat = "server" ID= "hypArticles" />
        </li>
        <li id="mnuQA" runat="server">
            <asp:HyperLink NavigateUrl = "~/QuestionAnswers.aspx" Text="Q & A" runat = "server" ID= "hypQA" />
        </li>
    </ul>
```

and JQuery,

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#menu li a').click(function () {

        $(this).addClass('highlight');

    });
});
```

The jquery code is not working properly.I am not able to add CSS class to clicked anchor..
Am I missing something or the approach is wrong..Please suggest

Comment: Does clicking the link re-load the page, or is that prevented somehow?

Comment: Yes,on clicking the link it loads the new page.

Comment: Then your JavaScript won't run, because the browser loads a new page.

Comment: if so, you have to modify your HTML code using server-side scripting (to add the current class to the clicked element).

Comment: I am using this list of anchors in User Control(used as header).This user control is used in Master page.After clicking the link the browser is hitting the breakpoint at .click().Does it requires Server side handlers..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to remove from the first selected as well before applying to the clikced one:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#menu li a').click(function (event) {

        $('#menu li a').removeClass('highlight');
        $(this).addClass('highlight');

        event.preventDefault(); // stop default event to stop reloading of page

    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add event.preventDefault() to the click event. Try this:

http://jsfiddle.net/xec4a/

```
$('#menu li a').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();    
    $(this).addClass('highlight');
    alert('class added');
});
```